Can a low power rated Class D Amplifier drive a Speaker with higher power
I am using a TPA3116D2 based 2.1 Class D amplifier to design a powerful Stereo Audio System. A sample module image is given below.

I believe, this is a popular amplifier module and many of the experts are familiar with this. It is rated for 2x50 Watts speakers + 1x100 Watts Subwoofer. I got the 2 speakers and the subwoofer, but the power ratings are slightly different. The speakers are rated 40 watt, 4 Ohm, 6" and the subwoofer is rated 200 watt, 4 Ohm, 8". So, even though the speakers are within the power rating of amplifier board, the Subwoofer is not. I have two questions.

Can this board drive the speakers and the subwoofer without getting damaged? If I understand correctly, the power rating of a speaker or subwoofer is the absolute maximum. But I am just worried if at max volume with very high bass there is a chance that the subwoofer would damage the circuit.

Can I use a 18V 25 Amps (450 watt) rated SMPS with a couple of 4700uF, 35V capacitors to power the amplifier with these 3 speakers? The module is rated to work between 12 - 24V. Wondering the power supply rated for higher power than the combined power rating of the amplifier and given the fact that the subwoofer is also rated more than what the board support, is such a Power Supply ok?


I am ok to sacrifice the full capacity of the sub woofer, I am kind of expecting the speakers to work just fine in this setup. Can someone please help?

You actually have the opposite problem: your amplifier L/R channel is 50W each, while your L/R speakers are rated at only 40W each. Meanwhile, you have 100W sub, and your speaker is rated 200W. So your sub is fine, but your L/R pair could possibly be blown up by this amp.
Specifically,

Your L/R channel power out (50W) exceeds your speaker handling (40W), so this could be an issue. On the other hand, you're not getting the most out of that 200W sub if you have only 100W to drive it (which you've stated you're ok with.)

Your power supply should be rated for your peak output, not what your speakers can handle. Having it higher than the amplifier rating is not a problem - you actually want that extra power so to better handle peak power, especially for the subwoofer which will be the main draw.


How to fix (1)? Check is if the amp power rating varies with supply voltage. Using a lower voltage to about 21V will limit the L/R channels to about 40W each and protect that speaker pair. Downside would also be reduced power to your sub, too.
MORE: the TPA3116D2 has a PLIMIT function set by a resistor, which you can use to limit the power to the output, behaving as if the supply rail were lower. Then you can use the full 24V. Read more about it on the data sheet.
Which leads to...
How to fix (2). I recommend using PLIMIT for L/R to protect the 40W speakers, and make the PSU 24V. This is a more common voltage than 18V, so you will have more PSU choices at possibly lower cost. 350-400W should be enough; 450W can't hurt.

This actually so simply clarifies my doubt. I never gave it a thought on the L/R speakers power rating and it was so implicit that either the amplifier or the L/R speakers will be impacted at the full power! Thanks for also giving the clue of PLIMIT resistor. Thank you so much!

I need a help sir. I came across some Chinese subwoofer modules as well. They basically works as low pass filter for the subwoofers alone. In a setup where I have a stereo amplifier to drive the LR speakers and a subwoofer module to drive the subwoofer separately, where should I attach the subwoofer modules? Before the amplifier where the audio input is fed in or after the amplifier? How do I connect a stereo output to the mono subwoofer module?

I am not an electronics guy, but in the process of making my own amplifier. So your guidance will help me solve the doubts I have with nobody else around to assist. I tried googling this questions, but ended up seeing how  a subwoofer sound box is connected to an amplifier unit. Got no guidance on how to connect the circuits.

Separate subwoofers often have internal amplifiers, so they take a line-in.

thanks for confirming. Really appreciate your help.
